# New TestNG installation

Tags: eclipse, testng

My Eclipse version is Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0). While I tried to install TestNG, it shows following error,

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  Software being installed: a.jre.javase 14.0.0
  Software currently installed: M2E - POM Editor using LemMinX language server (includes Incubating components) 2.0.0.20220729-1256 (org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.20220729-1256)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: M2E Maven POM File Editor using Wild Web Developer, Lemminx and Maven LS extension (requires Incubating components) 2.0.0.20220729-1256 (org.eclipse.m2e.editor.lemminx 2.0.0.20220729-1256)
    To: osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17))
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: M2E - POM Editor using LemMinX language server (includes Incubating components) 2.0.0.20220729-1256 (org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.20220729-1256)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.m2e.editor.lemminx [2.0.0.20220729-1256,2.0.0.20220729-1256].
```

How to solve this one.

Comment: According to the message, the upgrade to Eclipse 2022-09 could not be done because you are running Eclipse with Java 14, but parts of Eclipse 2022-09 require Java 17. Does installing _JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete_ 17.0.4 via _Help > Install New Software..._ working with the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/17/updates/release`](https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/17/updates/release) before doing the update work?

Answer (score 2):

According to the message, **running Eclipse with Java 14** installed on your system (so it cannot be upgraded by Eclipse) **prevents a complete upgrade** to Eclipse 2022-09 **because parts of Eclipse 2022-09** (or to be more specific, the [Maven support](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#201)) **require Java 17 or higher**.

As solution, [run Eclipse with Java 17 or higher](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) or even better, **install Java 17 as part of Eclipse** (so it will also be upgraded by Eclipse in the future):

- ***Help > Install New Software...***
- Work with: [**`https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/17/updates/release`**](https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/17/updates/release)
- Select and install ***JustJ** Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE **Complete***

Note: The Java version with which Eclipse is run is independent of the Java versions you use in your projects (configure the JDKs you want to use in your projects in the preferences *Java > Installed JREs*).

Comment: Yes, after I updated the Java version it's working fine. Thanks a lot for the solution.